# How do I copy a file to the clipboard in the terminal (linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, clipboard

I would like to copy a file to the clipboard with the terminal, like when right clicking a file and selecting "copy" in the gui. Someting like "cp test.txt" (without a destination) so whenever I want, I could right click and paste the file (or files) in the gui. Thank you

[image]

1. No file in clipboard
2. What I am trying to do: (copy a file to the clipboard with the terminal). Exactly like right clicking a file and selecting copy. (test.txt already on desktop)
3. Now the file is in the clipboard and I can paste it anywhere
4. File is pasted

Answer (score 5):

What you want to achieve isn't impossible, but looks like there isn't any universal solution. The only thing I managed to find was this question: [Copy file from commandline, paste into Gnome window or vice-versa](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41926/306529).

---

When you want to copy and move files via the X clipboard in CLI use `xclip-copyfile` and `xclip-pastefile`.

---

Additionally:

```
xclip -i -selection clipboard < ~/foo.c
```

This will copy the contents of file `~/foo.c` into CLIPBOARD (without `-selection clipboard` it will copy into PRIMARY).

---

Tools will be different on other systems (e.g. on Windows will be `copy`) or if you aren't using X server.

Comment: Thank you, but as i said I would like to copy a file not the contents of a file so whenever I want, I could right click and paste the file (or files) in the gui

Comment: Then `xclip-copyfile`

Comment: This isn't quite what I was asking, I edited the post and made it clearer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in the question, I would like to paste using the gui not the terminal.

Comment: Thank you! Yes i actually read that (Copy file from commandline, paste into Gnome window or vice-versa.) and it is exactly what i'm looking for, but I didn't understand the answer... Does it work only on gnome?

Comment: Sadly, I won' be of much more assistance as I'm not heavily GUI user

Comment: Got you, thank you very much for these detailed answers I highly appreciate it!